# Lock wait timeout exceeded MySQL

Tags: mysql

Well, I'm trying to delete duplicated rows in MySql.

To know what rows are duplicated I use this query:

```
select Path, COUNT(Path) from Entrega GROUP BY Path HAVING COUNT(Path) > 1;
```

And reading documentation, this query will delete duplicated items, and leave only one:

```
DELETE t1 FROM Entrega t1 INNER JOIN Entrega t2 WHERE t1.id > t2.id AND t1.Path = t2.Path
```

This simple query show me an alert that says

> Error SQL(1205): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting de transaction.

Why is it taking longer than expected?

Comment: The "Lock wait timeout exceeded" error message usually indicates that your query is waiting for another transaction to release a lock.

Comment: Can you modify the query with Limit clause and execute until duplicates are deleted; Like :

`DELETE t1 FROM Entrega t1 
INNER JOIN Entrega t2 
WHERE t1.id > t2.id AND t1.Path = t2.Path
LIMIT 100;`

Comment: If issue still persists; you can try optimizing server settings

Comment: @Tushar It's the only query I'm executing

Comment: Well, Did you try with limiting data ?

Comment: Yep, and I don't know if it's a problem of Heidi but I have an alert: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySql server version.."`